# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3457bc96ae, pid=1192, tid=0x00007f345e1ff700

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, jvm, tomcat8

I am using two company finger sdk . The project is running in java ee . I am getting the following error while executing the program. The crash is not always happening .

I have got this as the beginning :

```
 #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3457bc96ae, pid=1192, tid=0x00007f345e1ff700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsgfpamx.so+0xb6ae]  _DecodeANSITemplate+0x2e
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The problematic frame are as follows :

```
Stack: [0x00007f345e0ff000,0x00007f345e200000],  sp=0x00007f345e1fd000,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libsgfpamx.so+0xb6ae]  _DecodeANSITemplate+0x2e

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.JSGFPLib.MatchTemplate([B[BJ[Z)J+0
j  enroll.verify.FingerMatching.fingerprintVerify(LSecuGen/FDxSDKPro/jni/JSGFPLib;[B[B)Z+20
j  enroll.verify.FingerMatching.fingerPrintIndetify([B[[B)Z+64
j  era.data.FingerPrintVerification.fingerVerfyFromTemplate(Lera/data/LoginModel;)Ljava/util/List;+394
j  finger.servlet.FingerVerification.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+744
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+149
j  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+30
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+396
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+21
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V+430
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+151
j  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V+101
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+774
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+166
j  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+417
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+135
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+6
j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V+71
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V+199
j  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+624
j  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;+349
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun()V+166
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V+63
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run()V+4
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

I could not understand the crash log .[The crash log is given here](https://pastebin.com/HVtHy1rC)  . Can you please help me to understand the crash report ? How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the bug of SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.JSGFPLib.MatchTemplate implementation. As its package name says it is JNI, which it can make JVM crash. You should contact the implementor.

Comment: They have told it is not their bug .

Answer (score 0):

The crash happened in "libsgfpamx.so" file, you can see the Problematic frame indicating the crash location.

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsgfpamx.so+0xb6ae]  _DecodeANSITemplate+0x2e

You need to examine below calls
j  SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.JSGFPLib.MatchTemplate([B[BJ[Z)J+0
j  enroll.verify.FingerMatching.fingerprintVerify(LSecuGen/FDxSDKPro/jni/JSGFPLib;[B[B)Z+20
j  enroll.verify.FingerMatching.fingerPrintIndetify([B[[B)Z+64
j  era.data.FingerPrintVerification.fingerVerfyFromTemplate(Lera/data/LoginModel;)Ljava/util/List;+394
j  finger.servlet.FingerVerification.doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V+744
```

Before calling libsgfpamx.so check your parameters passed that may give you some clue.